# How to download an image from a website using login requests?

Tags: python, image, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using session in requests to do so -

```
payload ={ 'email':'xy@xyz.com', 'pass':'123'}
imgurl = 'http://erp.sangamuniversity.ac.in/Student/showimage.aspx?id=24218'
with session() as c:
    c.post('http://erp.sangamuniversity.ac.in/Default1.aspx', data=payload)
    response = c.get(imgurl)
    f = open("img.jpg", "w+")
    f.write(response)
```

But it is not saving the image from the img url to the desired img.jpg file. How can I do this?